# If I leave out the wp_die() in the testiframe function I get the '0' appended to my output. If I put it in, the page w/ iframe linked to it crashes

Tags: ajax, iframe

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_ajtestiframe','testiframe');

<?php
function testiframe() {
?>
    <head>
    <style>
    .aatest1 {color:red;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <span class="aatest1">This is a test</span><br>
<?php
    echo 'This is my iframe content<br>';
    var_dump($_GET);
}
    wp_die();
?>
```

Comment: there is no logged out user handler here, and no exit inside the handler. Was there a specific reason you chose the old `admin-ajax.php` approach rather than the newer modern REST API endpoints? The new approach give syou a shiny URL to make the request to and can tell you error messages in plain english rather than a cryptic `0`

Comment: You say "If I leave out the wp_die() in the testiframe function", but you put it _outside_ the function.

Comment: Jacob,  Yeah that was kind of dumb of me.  So every time my plugin loaded the file was included and my it bombed the whole loop.  Moving it inside the function did the trick.  Thanks!  Also Tom, I'll check out the REST API (new to me!_  Thanks for all.